# Rails mailer view template pass value send by a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, mailer

Its my first attempt to use the rails mailer to send email. I however is able to send plain emails but when I tried to pass the logged in user (current_user) name and params values send by the form I am getting the error. Undefined method 'params'.

payment_mailer.rb

```
class PaymentMailer < ApplicationMailer
    def success(user)
        mail(to: "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name} <#{user.email}>", subject: "Payment Successful")
    end
end
```

success.html.erb

```
<div class = "col-sm-12">
          <h1>Payment Successful</h1>
          <p>Dear <%= user.first_name %>, Thank you for being a part of our system<br>
            Your invoice (#<%= params[:id] %>) has been generated.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class = "clearfix"></div>
        <div class = "col-sm-6">
          <table class = "table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Paid Ammount</th>
                <th>Card Transaction Fee (2.9% + 0.30)</th>
                <th>Credited Ammount</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>&euro;<%= params[:amount] %></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <h3>Total credited amount in your Account is: </h3>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class = "clearfix"></div>
      </div>
```

payment_controller.rb

```
amount = params[:amount]
@user = current_user
netamt =  (amount.to_f - ((amount.to_f*2.9)/100 + 0.30))
payment = @user.payments.create(:amount => netamt, :method => "Card", :txn_code => params[:stripeToken])
@user.update_attribute(:balance, @user.balance+netamt)
PaymentMailer.success(current_user).deliver_now
```

Please guide me.

Comment: `params` is not accessable inside success mailer. you can get the 'id` and `amount` from your user table relations

Comment: If you need user's id then instead of params[:id] use user.id. And if you need id of some other table then pass it in parameters like you passed current_user

Comment: I would like use the id of the payments table and doing user.first_name too is generating error.

Comment: you need to use "@user" in your view instead of user, set "@user = user" in your mailer method and for payment you need to pass payment object from controller.

Comment: @GauravGupta thanks, It worked for the "@user.first_name" but how do I pass the id and amount which are generated before mailer action.

Comment: you can pass your payment object from controller, could you please add controller code.

Comment: I updated the controller code in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change in your payment controller after the payment, do like that

```
PaymentMailer.success(payment).deliver_now
```

And in your mailer do

```
class PaymentMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def success(payment)
    @payment = payment
    @user = payment.user
    mail(to: "#{@user.first_name} #{@user.last_name} <#{@user.email}>", subject: "Payment Successful")
  end
end
```

and in your mailer template use

```
@payment.id #for payment id

@payment.amount #for amount

@user.first_name #for user name
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller objects, such as `params` or `current_user` are not defined in the context of your mailers.

You'll need to either set these values on user, or pass them in as additional arguments in your mailer method. You'll also need to assign instance variables to access these values in your mailer views (same principle as passing instance variables defined in your controller to ActionView).

```
class PaymentMailer < ApplicationMailer
    def success(user, invoice_id, amount)
        @invoice_id = invoice_id
        @amount = amount

        mail(to: "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name} <#{user.email}>", subject: "Payment Successful")
    end
end
```

However, it seems like `amount`, `id`, and `user` are all variables of an `payment` object, so it sounds like the object you really should be passing `payment` to the `success` method, instead of `current_user`. Is this possible?

Comment: Do i need to modify **PaymentMailer.success(current_user).deliver_now** or add extra mailer action lines to get Id and amount

Comment: If you use the method in my example, you would call `PaymentMailer.success(current_user, invoice_id, amount).deliver_now`

Comment: `def success(user, invoice_id, amount)`  error __wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)__

Comment: And you're calling `PaymentMailer.success(current_user, invoice_id, amount).deliver_now` from your controller?

Comment: oh, sorry I missed it. Let me check it